# Combining 'n' Observables of the same type (RxJava)

Tags: java, asynchronous, reactive-programming, observable, rx-java

I have a code flow that generates an Iterable of Observables of the same type. I then go through them all, combining them and returning the result as an Observable. At the moment I'm using zip with a FuncN, which seems horrible and I think I've missed the point somewhere. Here's an example that uses a Map, it's obviously nonsense but you get the idea.

```
final ImmutableList.Builder<Map<String, Object>> observables = 
        ImmutableList.builder();
for (String key: keys) {
    if (someTest(key)) {
        observables.add(generateObservableMap(key));
    }
}

return Observable.zip(observables.build(), data -> {
    final Map<String, Object> result = Maps.newHashMap();

    // THIS IS REALLY UGLY
    for (Object d: data) {
        for (Object e: ((Map) d).entrySet()) {
            final Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) e;
            final String key = (Model) entry.getKey();
            final Object value = (AuthData) entry.getValue();
            result.put(key, value);
        }
    }

    return ImmutableMap.copyOf(result);
});
```

I'm sure there's a better way of doing this.

Comment: So you have an Observable<Observable<Map<String, Object>>> and want to transform that to an Observable<Map<String, Object>> by combining all the maps to one bigger map, right? Did you have a look at `reduce` - it corresponds to fold in some functional programming languages and seems to fit quite well: you start with an empty map and then in each step add the items of the next map to that map.

Comment: Sorry I just saw that you are starting with an Iterable<Observable<Map<String, Object>>> instead of an Observable<...> - but it can easily transformed with `Observable.from`.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually more a question about Java Collections than about RxJava. The part that you labelled as `REALLY UGLY` can be made a bit nicer using `putAll`:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> mergeMaps(Object... maps) {
    final Map<K, V> result = new HashMap<K, V>();
    for (Object map: maps) {
        // unchecked <K,V> require @SuppressWarnings
        result.putAll((Map<K,V>)map);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Notice that if the same key occurs in several maps, only the last value for it will be in the result.

You may wonder why I chose `Object...` as argument type instead of `Map<K,V>...`. The reason is that `FuncN` will have an `Object[]`, which cannot be cast to a `Map<K,V>[]`, because this would throw a `ClassCastException`, even if all elements in the array are of type `Map`.

Now if you have some `sampleObservables` inside an `Iterable<Observable<Map<String, Object>>>`, you can use `zip` and `mergeMaps` as follows:

```java
return Observable.zip(sampleObservables, new FuncN<Map<String, Object>>() {
    public Map<String, Object> call(Object... args) {
        return mergeMaps(args);
    }
});
```